# Which website for filling US Visitor Visa form?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, tourist-visas

I have been invited to attend the scientific conference in U.S. This is not sponsored by my company and will be a personal trip.

- It will be a B2 Visa/tourist visa?
- I am unable to locate exact website for the same.

This might appear less re-searched, but there are so many forum links, that appear in search result.

Please confirm the above two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[B-1](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/BusinessVisa%20Purpose%20Listings%20March%202014%20flier.pdf)**. Apply **[here](https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/)**. Follow [**this**](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/in/in-niv-visaapply.asp).